# Adding value to the dynamic HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5.1

i use Laravel 5 to build simple CMS.
I create HTML element according to value from my `attributes` table.
So, if i have 3 `attributes` like : `height`, `weight`, `dimesion` then i loop that value to create HTML element :

```
<input type='text' name='height' />
<input type='text' name='weight' />
<input type='text' name='dimension' />
```

When i have data from Controller look like this :

```
{"id":1,"attribute_name":"Weight","type":"text","description":"Weight Product in (gram)","created_at":"2015-09-07 04:16:52","updated_at":"2015-09-07 04:16:52"}
```

I want pass that data to specified HTML element, in above example i want to pass that data in : `<input type='text' name='weight' />`

So in my logic i must do :

1. Loop HTML creation according to `attributes` table value.
2. Loop Data from Controller
3. Compare if `attribute_id` == `product->attribute_id`, then i create HTML element and set it value.

Here is my implementation :

```
<div class="box-body">
      @if ($attributes != null)
        @foreach ($attributes as $attr)
          <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('', $attr->attribute_name) !!}

            @foreach ($product->attributes as $pAttr)
                  @if ($attr->id == $pAttr->id)
                    @if ($attr->type == "text")
                      <input type="text" name="attributes[{{ $attr->id }}][value]" value="{{ $pAttr->pivot->value }}" class="form-control" />
                    @else
                      <textarea id="content2" name="attributes[{{ $attr->id }}][value]">{{ $pAttr->pivot->value }}</textarea>
                    @endif
                  @else 
                    @if ($attr->type == "text")
                      <input type="text" name="attributes[{{ $attr->id }}][value]" value="" class="form-control" />
                    @else
                      <textarea id="content2" name="attributes[{{ $attr->id }}][value]"></textarea>
                    @endif
                  @endif
            @endforeach

          </div>
        @endforeach
      @endif
    </div>
```

But, i get this following result :
[image]
How to fix that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="box-body">
    @if ($attributes != null)
        {{-- START: loop attributes --}}
        @foreach ($attributes as $attr)
            <div class="form-group">
                {{-- START: loop product's attributes --}}
                @foreach ($product->attributes as $pAttr)
                    @if ($attr->type == "text")
                    <input type="text" name="attributes[{{ $attr->id }}][value]" value="{{ ($attr->id == $pAttr->id)? $pAttr->pivot->value : '' }}" class="form-control" />
                    @else
                      <textarea id="content2" name="attributes[{{ $attr->id }}][value]">{{ ($attr->id == $pAttr->id)? $pAttr->pivot->value : '' }}</textarea>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                {{-- END: loop product's attributes --}}
            </div>
        @endforeach
        {{-- END: loop attributes --}}
    @endif
</div>
```

I have removed the labels because they did not have text inside.

Answer (score 0):

> **Answer ✔**

I already have the solution for my problem. I build dynamic HTML
Element in my Controller. So controller will pass HTML element with
the specific value.

Here is my code :

```
$attrElements = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
            $element = array();
            if ($attr->type == 'text') {
                $element = array(
                    'id' => $attr->id,
                    'name' => $attr->attribute_name,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'element' => "<input type='text' name='attributes[". $attr->id ."][value]' value='' class='form-control' />"
                );
            } else {
                $element = array(
                    'id' => $attr->id,
                    'name' => $attr->attribute_name,
                    'type' => 'editor',
                    'element' => "<textarea name='attributes[". $attr->id ."][value]' class='form-control'></textarea>"
                );
            }

            array_push($attrElements, $element);
        }

        foreach ($attrElements as &$attrEl) {
            foreach ($product->attributes as $pAttr) {
                if ($pAttr->id == $attrEl['id']) {
                    // echo $pAttr->id  . " == " . $attrEl['id'] . " ? " . ($pAttr->id == $attrEl['id']);
                    // echo "<br/>";
                    if ($attrEl['type'] == 'text') {
                        $attrEl['element'] = "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='attributes[". $attrEl['id'] ."][value]' value='" . $pAttr->pivot->value . "' />";
                    } else {
                        $attrEl['element'] = "<textarea name='attributes[". $attrEl['id'] ."][value]' class='form-control'>" . $pAttr->pivot->value . "</textarea>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And it works! :D
Thank you..